# Account or Contact Transactions relationship in Laravel 4.2

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, orm, entity-relationship, relationships

Ok, here is what I am trying to achieve, I have an accounts table that contains bank accounts, a transactions table that contains individual transactions, there are multiple fields in this table:

```
id
from
to
amount
date
```

The from and two fields are either a contact_id or an account_id.

For example, a user is creating a transaction to a contact from an account and vice versa

How can I set this up as a relationship in laravel?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how familiar you are with Laravel, but you have to make a 'Transaction' model containing this:

```
<?php

class Transaction extends \Eloquent
{
   protected $table = 'transactions';

   public function sender(){
      return $this->belongsTo('User', 'from'); //One-to-one relationship between Transaction and User
   }

   public function receiver(){
      return $this->belongsTo('User', 'to');
   }
}
```

It might be more elegant to use 'sender_id' and 'receiver_id' in the transactions table, so it looks like this:

```
public function sender(){
   return $this->belongsTo('User', 'sender_id');
}

public function receiver(){
   return $this->belongsTo('User', 'receiver_id');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I am reasonably familiar with Laravel, however the logic of relationships still make me stop to think sometimes. Anyway, back to the point, how does this help in my example where the 'sender' or 'receiver' could be from one Account to another, from an Account to Contact, from a Contact to Account etc?